# Google Script Escaping Ampersand and Throwing Error in Trello using RESTful

Tags: javascript, restful-url, trello, google-sheets

I'm using a script from Google Sheets that checks for new cards in Trello.  I have it automated to run every so often from Google, but sometimes it throws an error in Trello and I've narrowed it down to the fact that Google is escaping my ampersands even though I don't have them escaped.  I thought I might solve this problem by escaping the ampersands myself in the code, but that consistently throws errors in Trello.

Here is the line of code that I am meaning to send to Trello:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/boards/myboardname/cards?actions=createCard&since=2014-09-27T01:06:00.000Z&fields=shortLink,name,url&key=mykey&token=mytoken
```

But when I get the error report, it says it sent:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/boards/myboardname/cards?actions=createCard&amp;since=2014-09-27T01:06:00.000Z&amp;fields=shortLink,name,url&amp;key=mykey&amp;token=mytoken
```

Does anyone know if I can make it stop doing this?

Comment: Please someone help us,
same problem with a xml attribute with the & in the url